# How do I draw a credible velocity vs. time graph using Locators?

Tags: graphics, functions, fitting, locator

This is partly a math question, partly a *Mathematica* question.

For educational purposes, I'm making a simple demonstration to create a velocity over time graph from six locators.  On the basis of input from the user in the velocity graph (he moves the graph control points), a distance over time graph and an acceleration over time graph will be automatically produced through integration and differentiation.

Trouble is, a piecewise linear function leaves corners for which the derivative is undefined. There is also a real-world issue: an object cannot instantaneously jump from an acceleration of 2 to 3. I would like the velocity function to "round" the corners.

I don't want to use `Bezier` or `BSpline` because the control points do not lie on the graph of the function.

I suspect that `Fit` will be of use, but I'm unsure what model to use that will have the function intersect with the points where the locators are positioned.

Suggetions about the math (which model) and/or the *Mathematica* code are appreciated.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

[image: velocity over time graph]

```
Manipulate[
 LocatorPane[
  Dynamic[pts, (pts = #; 
     pts = Function[
        pnt, {.25 Round[4 pnt[[1]]], .1 Round[10 pnt[[2]]]}] /@ 
       pts) &],
  data = (Sort@pts);
  Dynamic@Show[{ListPlot[{data},
      ImageSize -> 550,
      Joined -> True,
      AspectRatio -> 1/2,
      Epilog -> 
       Dynamic@MapIndexed[Text[#2[[1]], Offset[{5, 10}, #1]] &, 
         data],
      BaseStyle -> 12,
      AxesLabel -> {"time (min)", "velocity \n(m/s)("},
      PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {-20, 20}}, Axes -> True, 
      ImageSize -> 450]}]],

 {{pts, {{0, 0}, {4, 12}, {7, 12}, {23, -12}, {25, -12}, {27, -6}}}, 
  ControlType -> None}]
```

Comment: Can't you just use interpolation with order 2 or more?

Comment: I have never used Interpolation but a quick reading of the documentation suggests that this may be indeed what I need.  Would you like to elaborate on your suggestion as an answer to the question?

Comment: You can also take a look on `Locator` documentation. `Properties & Relations` example 2.

Comment: @Kuba Example 2 is `Locator[Dynamic[{x,y}]] will reset the values of x and y when the locator object is moved; Locator[{x,y}] will not. `  I don't see the relation to the question.(The code correctly uses `Dynamic`.) Perhaps you can explain.

Comment: I am confused, I do not know where is this quote from. [Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Locator.html?q=Locator&lang=en) for `Locator/Properties & Relations/`, second example is about "Use LocatorPane to use locators on complex objects:" which is related. Not by syntax but by interpolation of points.

Comment: Mine was from 9.0.1 documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, using `Interpolation[]` is likely your best bet. It behaves strangely with certain location positions, but still makes for a useful demonstration.

```
Manipulate[LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts, (pts = #;
     pts = 
      Function[pnt, {.25 Round[4 pnt[[1]]], .1 Round[10 pnt[[2]]]}] /@
        pts) &], data = (Sort@pts);
  fx = Interpolation[pts, x, InterpolationOrder -> 5];
  Dynamic@
   Grid[{{Show[{ListPlot[pts, ImageSize -> 550, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
         Epilog -> 
          Dynamic@MapIndexed[Text[#2[[1]], Offset[{5, 10}, #1]] &, 
            data], BaseStyle -> 12, 
         AxesLabel -> {"time (s)", "velocity \n(m/s)"}, 
         PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {-20, 20}}], 
        Plot[fx, {x, Min[pts[[All, 1]]], 
          Max[pts[[All, 1]]]}]}]}, {Plot[
       Evaluate[D[fx, x]], {x, Min[pts[[All, 1]]], 
        Max[pts[[All, 1]]]}, ImageSize -> 550, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
       BaseStyle -> 12, 
       AxesLabel -> {"time (s)", "acceleration \n(m/s^2)"}, 
       PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, Automatic}]},
     {Plot[
       Evaluate[Integrate[fx, x]], {x, Min[pts[[All, 1]]], 
        Max[pts[[All, 1]]]}, ImageSize -> 550, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
       BaseStyle -> 12, 
       AxesLabel -> {"time (s)", "displacement \n(m)"}, 
       PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, Automatic}]}}]], {{pts, {{0, 0}, {4, 
     12}, {7, 12}, {23, -12}, {25, -12}, {27, -6}}}, 
  ControlType -> None}]
```

[image: plots]

Comment: Shouldn't your third plot be labeled "distance" on its y-axis and not "velocity"?

Comment: It was labelled that way in the code but I forgot to change the screenshot. Fixed.

Comment: Still a small error: displacement should have units (m) not (m/s).

Comment: Are the units even consistent? Since the original plot was (m/s) vs (min), there should be some factors of 60 floating around.

Comment: Since the `Manipulate` is for educational purposes, I think changing it to the m-k-s system is fine.

Comment: The units issues are easily handled. The important thing is that this works quite well.